# Magento Layout XML

Tags: php, xml, magento

I need to understand this in Magento . In `page.xml`, for the following block :

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
```

I need to `app/design/package/theme/template/page/template/links.phtml`

Then for the following block ::

```
<block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
```

Why I need to lookup `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Welcome.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases you need to look inside the block classes:
for `block type="page/template_links"` the class is `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links` and can be found in the file `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php`
If you look inside the class you'll see:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->setTemplate('page/template/links.phtml');
}
```

This points to the file `app/design/package/theme/template/page/template/links.phtml`
The class for the second block only sets the welcome message, and has no template.

Comment: Thanks Emi, I understood the matter.

Comment: You should probably look into the abstract class Mage_Core_Block_Abstract at functions like toHtml, _toHtml, getChildHtml, _getChildHtml and then see the class Mage_Core_Block_Template that extends the previous one

Answer (score 0):

In magento we set the template in xml or set template in Action. In your xml, you set as a block file. so by calling block function inside the template you can access the function.In welcome.php you can set the value and get the value in template.